# Setting Quercus database connection encoding to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, connection, database, quercus

Now we are going to use Java class in my website developed with PHP and MySQL. I came to know Quercus and it worked well. But only problem is encoding.

Quercus is providing ISO8859 encoding in default and all database in UTF-8 is not shown properly like `???`.

Answer (score 1):

By the tests I ran,

We can not use full UTF-8 on quercus.
For some reason the php.ini unicode.semantics is not kick in.

I read some blogs that state exactly the same thing.

Comment: This is not an answer. This might be better as a comment